# If I move a window quickly to the right or left I often find myself in a different space. Is there a way to prevent this

Tags: macos, spaces

If I'm working on an app or in another window I will occasionally slide an idle window or app to the right or left to just get it out of the way temporarily. Often I go too far and find myself in a different space. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It shouldn't be the speed you move the window, but how long you leave the mouse butted up to the screen edge. Takes about a second to respond on my machine. I'm sure the 'cure' really is to make better use of the Spaces you have, so you don't keep having to move things out of the way - or use Mission Control to expose the next app.

Comment: Yea I know the workarounds but when rushed I have a tendency to just move something out of the way. Can that 1 sec delay be increased?

Answer (score 1):

You must hover with the mouse at the edge of the space for a certain, very brief, period of time before the space switches. To avoid this, you can increase the timed delay such that you never inadvertently trigger the behavior:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 9;
killall Dock;
```